# Uploading Base64 images to supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

My website wants to reduce the amount of things users can do with the images...so for added security, we want to keep the image sources as a base64 strings instead of a supabase storage URL. Is this possible through supabase storage, do will I have to save the string in the db?

Answer (score 6):

```
import { decode } from 'base64-arraybuffer'

const image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA='

const base64 = image.split('base64,')[1]

const { data, error } = await supabase
   .storage
   .from('avatars')
   .upload('public/avatar1.png', decode(base64), {
       contentType: 'image/png'
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your image as base64 you need to save it as a record in your table.

With storage you can create a complex policy and download files from storage and don't share links directly.